# How do I send user to external URL via an iBeacon

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ibeacon

I am new to the world of iBeacons and Objective-C so please bear with me

I have a very simple app built now that updates a Label when the device approaches an iBeacon. What is the Objective-C code sending the device to an external URL?

For example, as you approach the iBeacon, the device is taken to a Youtube video with an explanation of what you ware seeing.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two problems: first you need to come up with your own local or remote database in which to look up the beacon's UUID/major/minor and determine the URL you feel should be associated.  Next you need to know how to "send the device to an external URL" in an iOS app, something you can doubtless research.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will do what you want, but it will only work if the app is in the foreground:

```
CLLocationManager *_locationManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] identifier: @"any-radius-networks-ibeacon-default-uuid"];
    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.radiusnetworks.com/radbeacon/"]];
}
```

You'd have to add extra logic to make it open special URLs for special iBeacons.